# Having connection problem with python: badstatusline

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, raspberry-pi3

I am using raspberry pi eith jessy version of raspbian running in it. I have updated python and pip both. Now I am having some problems while installing a module using pip.

```
 pip3 install openssl
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py:163: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: OpenSSL version 1.0.1 is no longer supported by the OpenSSL project, please upgrade. A future version of cryptography will drop support for it.
  utils.CryptographyDeprecationWarning
Collecting openssl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x17\x03\x03\x02Á²õ8$\x02\x8b\x87&#´¶X3rqRd`°\x06ä¾ª5l\x91£è\x81Ü\x14^ùé{ý\x8fÝÁ\x8bJ\x80¿\x06\'³Ë\x96\x07j\x0fÚd\x9e7ï\x01O\x15R\x1en\x9c\x83J}è×Iá\x8c\x15\x17¾w¦Y\x85\x81;\x7f\x06\x93ÂAÉ\x9fÐFióÿã.õ5âì\x1dþ\x8f\x8eIÆ<\x1a5ñ\x94§\x94æmtñR¿\x18è1+¥Ï\x98\x10£\x1d\x03¥óþ\x1cñ¸+ÿ-íê¥tÑùq}FD\x85,M\\ª[\'\x97MT\x04K\x10³KýÂâë[ú\x81G\x06[ÁZ¢+\x88\x93Vô\x80\x05ßØ\x96Ñ\x1e`A`¸\x0b§áë~A¬\x8bÒ±\x00Þ\x9dØEw-\x0c\'\x80í&Ý/\x97àç\x96\x8bò;µ,4å\x90\x16^Ìç\x80p{\x1fÖñ²z\x0bdê\x9b£=ðXûäá<y£/"@Él¡²\x94ps;é\x1bs\x0e\x1dÃm0©\x04\x905ó{Ç^\x82AµA8ÏïvÄK\x9cKIJ\x02J\x13û\x88\x1bö£ë½\x97Ô\x07\x94.<.ðgßÿ\x86È\t¿Þs\x80t¸\x9bl)\x85O\x03®¿È\tþp!«Ø^!\x03è|\x18zÖ\xa05Ý£ñ\x9aÖÈx¹\x8f°\x15Å(r\x15¬I,ó¬\x08#ªáì\x00ï¢!}2ìcï\x85\x8dñI<³ØÛ\tNWAìÿÀ\x91c¬\x91\x05+TÁ):ON\x8a0\xa0\x85âÊuì\rWW\x9eÖ¶ìKZ\x8c*\x14\x98\x0bèÃ\x0fèÎ0\x1d/\x060Ä¼öi«Ê%7Ú\x8fÜ\x99\x81\'ìa\x86b6³u³¸\x00ð\x00ÊCáá\x1cöÁî¥\rå?t`¬ENºj\x7fTõ\x7fÞyì¥ÔCS\\¯\x85¬:L\x1d9<\x8d!:8ötM\x00£m®ô8\x95¨Ù÷÷-Æ\t\x0eýÃ\xa00Î\x93¸ÒN\x915\\e¥ëò`+ë\x16äÓ\x98:¢\x8c\x89/ÓÚbö\x80Ø÷\x00\x84\x95£¥B\r¾¶Û½\x9c)\x829Ö Ó81¬\x86\x90>W£\xadº-8&\x1dÙýpH\x1bëÚ¼\x9aó=ÿ¬Ã\xadóDèJ¾ùe=½\x9d\x94s\x1e\x00\x12 û38zy2\x8e¢BÎ%\x06n\x12w\x12Õ\x11\x01\x7fâ\x96ÅË\x0cäª\x9dgcY\x84Lé\x90¼9KzÆGÀÀËê\x16LI\x8fc\x1bB5Â÷\x11Þ\x12\x84\n',))': /simple/openssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x17\x03\x03\x02¾\x12L\x7fîO\x06[\x00ùlÔÏ\x92\x9d\\\x05æám}Ès9\x99\x93\'Aë\x06âüÀ\'\x98_Yÿl¹¯\x1b\x16\x1f\x0fÜ\x9f\t\x0b.ÚÕªîÝh¦È3»%öÖú£H{²XäÕ\x13¢ÜP\x83\x90çi³*Ã)\x18¾¨ÞLÜ\x87\tüKò\x9eu?Ñ-7®±Y¹\x82\x95Ô4\x87#ô¬p3×Æ\x01\x80\x16Æ©·\x9c\x05@\x83\x11b#Ç\x82\x17ß\x83à\x96m¿ÄX"¢`a&-àG\x0bçkµ\x16üs\x19\x93rÛE\x96\x85®deâÄ\x84(j\x07H%\x81i\rr\x1b\rÓ>Ò\x96ÆÞô\xad\x87´¥\x9eÎk/¬\x183|g±{?5Ôd \x05j\x81ÖXÛe\x8fHN*ÝÄ`b@U¿\x0b\x12¥oÈ¯^\x8b\x1etÐ\x7f^Ð]þ\x04Ýßô¡½6Ím\x99¬¤e|_Aq¾¦è\x83ïÊ\x05¢\x1a+/â#sâ\x0fez\x1c\x8eÏo3ýí\x11À3\x99àæ¨p3ñ\x0fiïzJe%\x17÷fûó\x9eä*\x8bþ\x1b\x10×\x18Z\x0eu¢a ðø[\\\xad\x88Í\x19+§³Ybh÷\x86áNyÅ\x98|\n',))': /simple/openssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x17\x03\x03\x02¾$Ï@r¢]\x93\x1f]É³-wüÉ\x16\x16-ò\x0eç"Àk\x9aºnæ*¦\x1f\x982Yf\x808KB\x14ÊG¡]\x06H\x86Òà\x15\'ÿ\x14;½{m\x1b\x1aÒÿzq\x0fbîÓ2\x91\x8cBY¦Ã/µøUG\x93\n',))': /simple/openssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x17\x03\x03\x02¾Vã;\x84öÙ[ÍB.ú\x03\x91vè_^ÞßPy\x1b\x1d\x86Êµ*¤¾p£8|\x9c¹ÜóP\x84\x8f©b\x9dv7Ëq|\x1cX{GÝSÖ\x85\x1dÈ\x9bÆ\x80VÍ\x9b\x033VÒ\x1f$Ç\x05È°+\x13ÿ\x93ÿúM\x96A\x1a/\t\x82\x14,ç½~Q´\x80Ê]\x96\x0e^)V×}\x94Q\x0cAvJ\r\x17i§(\x93VcJ\x1e\x7f\x19àývúd\x81h*Ø\x05+¸n\x80&îÍÒú¬Àk0º_öOò\x07°ÔWAf\xadõÐd5\x8cOÛ<\x01ÿ\'\\$\x8aP¦ö\x8fû\x8dm\x08Wfð>Ã\x00\x99dÑS£eñáÇ\x95Ì\x8c\x95lÊ7õ´\x08M÷\x9f5\x02\x04÷\x06\x8e6ctH\x06C¬otÒ±S{\x14ø\x93½\x16÷\x83\x7fÎo¶\x10ÜQ\x10Y§\x0eA¡=\x1a.ewF\x02\x90\x1b¯UR¡\x9fh)O5oû-»\x81\x89\x03,ÜÙää\x80Öë+\x19Wf&\x10s\x1fÃ$\x13\x83z\r\x9d0®¹®q\xa0äÚ4ü@Í\x95îu³\x92áO"··r\x94È£r\x01e\x83±Ö`\x920ÊâéYïp84Ó\x96ä3c\x16ÀÛãáÏ \x1c\x1e*d\x1e\x0e^S%:\x95Î«í\x83¶Jh½\x1aA\x87\x9fk\x16\x86íGPÎ\x8b#¦{\x8cjWW°l[ùÛ\x93\x9f\x16¡±\n',))': /simple/openssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x17\x03\x03\x02¾â\'\x88\x01ß@%D\x14G\x81njá³æq»ÛÿOp\'áa¨\x1f²<â¥+\x19\t\tMÈL}!v\x9bvíËªuñxy\x95ÎT|O|$\x0e\x0ei\x1b8\x01\x90\x9cü`Û~Ñù?P³\x81=\x9b~Üßy\x08òt\x0cmô´ñË¬eà\x96-\x84VÑöRÙÊø:Æ¥zÂÃn:Pø\xa0¶º\x16«1\x1b?Ì$Zø;\x02\x8dñ\x0bu´á"A\x16\x9dY¥¸\x82¦%Zúk\x7f=\x1d4¾GÑÆ¢Â³\r\rú®0\x84à|\x92\x97\x02ät3\x05\x8b^[§ÒÝwwí®¦Fu\x0b÷\x80\x1f\x9d\x89Vá«7\x040ÝW\x02\x87zØ\x03\x8f®%Ì\x92=1\x8dÝã5z\x04Íÿ×ý\x8d½ô1\x14\ráØÊ"I9F\x95\x9b\x08ÃÉàuö\x98©\x1dØ\x84Ð«ú\'vLÃe\x95ÌhK\x01é]·É\x8d`\\lFÒ:XR_X\x16TuÏIÂ\x8f½KÅáp\x97{êHù\x9b¡»¼Ý\x07iÈ¥kó32\x94~8áÓÕÃ\x82ÇØ1 P7ðÒæUh\x1e«OÓWùöV?%MÕÖ\x1aß*\x08\x9cé\x82\x96¦\\tý£IR1ÌçøÇ\x19&Ö\x942\x14W2UUÅ@2\x930ß\x13Ð<õk\x1fl´ñ\x18oq\x14ÍëXÖ\x95IìvÒ¾]å:.\x08;=¸IråÑó¶Ö¬º½-\x92®_\x9cÁS\x81\x95,ÏO^\x97\x19ayK¤çs\x19\x1d©º@ð\x99ó¾r\x1b;2\x9f»_æ¦90õ_õÌøâ|ãë\x18Tßy&òx#§Ä\t\x7f\x95g\x8aZ_7Õ\x0c¦ÅÄî@ÇðÜ>\x1e0\x8d\x8fC%â2ßÇW?0ÖBÆ½ýÊè9Ià\x03µ»ç\x82\x15¶µû\xad×·£k\x95s\x83ðÐ®¾ÃÕ=!¢Üì\n',))': /simple/openssl/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openssl (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for openssl
```

and when I uses gTTS like online APi's

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1224, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 390, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 372, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: ?�������iètmÃÉÖÑ!ÌG1jûÇÖ:=(Ã}$ÈÎÙFX`àÙZûqNÿac­cetÏ³ÙLþüú¶#(èEí2ÔÉf<(0Öº®8Î;¢?ÞnÔ=ÎeÍ


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 368, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1224, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 390, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 372, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x17\x03\x03\x05?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01iè\x07tmÃÉ\x85Ö\x99Ñ\x14!ÌG1jûÇ\x9aÖ:=\x1f(Ã}$ÈÎ\x1eÙF\x93\x02\x10X\x18`àÙZû\x91\x01\x05q\x19Nÿ\x0cac\xad\x1ccetÏ³ÙLþüú\x9b¶#\x8f(èEí2ÔÉf<(0Öº®8Î;¢?Þn\x81Ô\x88=ÎeÍ\n',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 189, in write_to_fp
    part_tk = self.token.calculate_token(part)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gtts_token/gtts_token.py", line 28, in calculate_token
    seed = self._get_token_key()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gtts_token/gtts_token.py", line 55, in _get_token_key
    response = requests.get("https://translate.google.com/")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x17\x03\x03\x05?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01iè\x07tmÃÉ\x85Ö\x99Ñ\x14!ÌG1jûÇ\x9aÖ:=\x1f(Ã}$ÈÎ\x1eÙF\x93\x02\x10X\x18`àÙZû\x91\x01\x05q\x19Nÿ\x0cac\xad\x1ccetÏ³ÙLþüú\x9b¶#\x8f(èEí2ÔÉf<(0Öº®8Î;¢?Þn\x81Ô\x88=ÎeÍ\n',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/pi/UBUNTU 19_0/test1.py", line 74, in <module>
    assistant(myCommand())
  File "/media/pi/UBUNTU 19_0/test1.py", line 56, in assistant
    tts.save('hello.mp3')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 249, in save
    self.write_to_fp(f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 194, in write_to_fp
    str(e))
gtts.tts.gTTSError: Connection error during token calculation: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x17\x03\x03\x05?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01iè\x07tmÃÉ\x85Ö\x99Ñ\x14!ÌG1jûÇ\x9aÖ:=\x1f(Ã}$ÈÎ\x1eÙF\x93\x02\x10X\x18`àÙZû\x91\x01\x05q\x19Nÿ\x0cac\xad\x1ccetÏ³ÙLþüú\x9b¶#\x8f(èEí2ÔÉf<(0Öº®8Î;¢?Þn\x81Ô\x88=ÎeÍ\n',))
```

I have seen several answers on the web. but none of that were,nt satisfying.

- Python : 3.4
- OS : raspbian Jessie
- Occured when Updating python pip and openssl.

Comment: There are packages `openssl-python` and `pyOpenSSL` that can be installed with pip. No package named `openssl` on my system.

Comment: But this will also happens when I am installing another modules or using apis